# Доступ к элементу через $ref in vue3?

Tags: vue.js

Как получить достпуп к элементу через $ref вместо qverySelector ?
Пример

```
const { swiper } = document.querySelector('.swiper-container');
```

Answer (score 1):

При использовании "нового" Composition API, рефы на элементы шаблона в коде становятся доступны после монтирования компонента и первичного рендеринга разметки (а именно - [начиная с `onMounted`](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html)).
Vue автоматически присваивает ссылки на элементы ref-переменным, при совпадении имен (см. ниже, это проще понять увидев код).

Общий паттерн использования рефа элемента, имеет следующий вид:

```
<div ref="foo">...</div>
```

```
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const foo = ref(null);  // объявляем реф (с начальным значением null)
    // в setup, данный реф и будет иметь значение null - т.к. код setup выполняется синхронно, а замена значения произойдет ПОЗЖЕ, при первом рендеринге

    onMounted(() => {
      // тут Vue уже присвоила рефу новое значение (ссылку на DOM-объект), потому что имя рефа элемента совпало с именем рефа возвращенного из setup
      console.log('Вот объект нашего элемента из рефа:', foo.value);
    });
    return {
      foo,    // обязательно добавляем в возвращаемый из setup объект, делая данный реф доступным для использования
    };
  },
};
```

То есть, общий принцип: указываем реф в шаблоне, атрибутом элемента  в `setup` объявляем реф с тем же именем  возвращаем его в составе результирующего объекта (конечно, тоже в одноименном свойстве).

---

При использовании рендер-функции вместо шаблона - реф элемента указывается в объекте параметров (свойство `ref`), то есть:

```
render: h => h('div', { ref: 'foo' })
```

---

Более подробно изложено [в оф. документации Vue 3](https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html).